# Correct way to reference class\method in another file

Tags: php, oop

I have class that I have set up like this:

```
use MVC\Model;
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class ModelsAuth extends Model {
```

In my `ModelsAuth` class, I have this member function:

```
public function validateToken($token) {
}
```

I am using this to autoload my classes:

```
// autoload class
function autoload($class) {
    // set file class
    $file = SYSTEM . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file))
        require_once $file;
    else
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Class { %s } Not Found!', $class));
}

// set autoload function
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Is it possible to call this class and function from outside the class?

I have tried:

```
$authorization = new \MVC\Model\ModelsAuth();
$authorization->validateToken($token);
```

and

```
$authorization = MVC\Model\ModelsAuth::validateToken($token);
```

Both return a class not found error.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong with this approach?

Comment: are you using `composer`?

Comment: Do you have any form of class autoloading enabled?

Comment: @El_Vanja - yes, I have edited the original post to show my autoload code.

Comment: @Lessmore - yes, I am using composer to load some outside packages.

Comment: @zeropsi try `composer dump-autoload` then test again

Comment: Sorry to see the downvotes. Please offer up any suggestions to help me make this more complete and better questions for the community.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared a namespace for your class, so it's not clear that it will exist as `MVC\Model\ModelsAuth` and it's probably just going into the root namespace as `\ModelsAuth`. You probably want something like this:

```
namespace MVC\Model;

class ModelsAuth extends \MVC\Model {
    ...
}
```

Which can also be specified as:

```
namespace MVC\Model;

use MVC\Model;

class ModelsAuth extends Model {
    ...
}
```

I'm not fond of either of these options however, because then you've got a base class named `\MVC\Model` and a namespace named `\MVC\Model`, which is somewhat confusing. I'd recommend putting your base class as an abstract into the `\MVC\Model` namespace, in a file named `MVC/Model/AbstractModel.php` like this:

```
namespace MVC\Model;

abstract class AbstractModel {
    ...
}
```

And then your model in a file name `MVC/Model/MyModel.php` like this:

```
namespace MVC\Model;

class MyModel extends AbstractModel {
    ...
}
```

This way, all your models are in the same namespace and the same directory.

Also, if you use a [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloader then most of these sorts of issues will go away.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Understanding the confusion, if I added:
`namespace MVC\Model;

use MVC\Model;

class ModelsAuth extends Model {` to my `ModelsAuth.php` file, how would I then call then call functions from outside of the class?

Comment: I'm still a little confused at the proper way to achieve this. Once I added the `namespace` to my `ModelsAuth` class, I am still getting errors when trying reference the `validateToken` from outside of the class.